# Возможно ли создать приложение для android, чтобы выполнял код от php и как это сделать

Tags: php, android, мобильные-приложения

Есть некий php скрипт. И например если в приложении нажимаешь кнопочку,  то этот скрипт выполняется. Возможно это или надо переделывать код на java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно. Это делается примерно таким образом:
1) Пишется API, к которому можно обращаться и менять какие-то данные и т.д.
2) При нажатии на кнопку в приложении происходит обращение к этому API.